# Subtrair um valor de uma soma (SUM) em SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Boa tarde! Eu tenho uma consulta SQL, que busca e soma a quantidade de créditos que um determinado usuário possui:

```
SELECT *, SUM(quantidade) as total_creditos FROM creditos INNER JOIN usuarios ON creditos.id_usuario = usuarios.id WHERE creditos.id_usuario = '$id_usuario'`
```

Na tabela creditos, tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Tabela creditos]

Um usuário pode ter vários inserts na tabela, com X créditos.

**A pergunta é: tem como eu fazer um consulta e diminuir (deletar) um valor Y da SOMA total de créditos de um usuário?**

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Qual a condição do valor a ser substraído? Um determinado id de crédito,  usuário...?

Comment: ID do usuário. Está no final da consulta. Seria o consumo de um determinado item... qualquer valor, mas teria que alterar na tabela!

Comment: Uma maneira de você substrair, é não incluir ele no SUM(), ou seja, filtrar esse valor na consulta adicionando essa condição no WHERE junto com o ID do usuário que já está ali, ou usando a funcao IF dentro do SUM para substituir ele por zero. Outra possibilidade é subtrair esse valor com uma subquery SUM(quantidade) - (SELECT...). O que não ficou claro pra mim é o critério que identifica o "determinado item" para que se possa criar uma solução com ele.

Comment: Então Gustavo, no meu caso, o usuário irá usufruir do crédito disponível dele (determinado por ele mesmo a quantidade). Mas como @Emerson Ferreira Bezerra me explicou, o banco estava inviável da minha forma de pensar. Acabei fazendo como ele sugeriu: criar o campo debito e fazer o cálculo para saber a quantidade atual de créditos do usuário:  `SELECT *, (SUM(credito) - SUM(debito)) as total_creditos FROM creditos INNER JOIN usuarios ON creditos.id_usuario = usuarios.id WHERE creditos.id_usuario = '$id_usuario'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está fazendo de forma dinâmica uma soma total das quantidades de crédito, não há como diminuir algum valor desse total diretamente de forma permanente. Você precisará de alguma forma registrar esse valor a ser descontado.

Penso em dois caminho diferentes que podem ser seguidos:

- Criar uma nova tabela onde seriam lançados os débitos dos usuários e em sua query adicionar essa tabela e subtrair esses valores de débitos dos créditos para saber o saldo do(s) usuário(s)
- Utilizar a mesma tabela de crédito, realizando lançamentos com valor de crédito negativo para o(s) usuário(s) em questão. Dessa forma as alterações seriam minimizadas.

A primeira opção parece ser mais elegante e robusta, a segunda mais prática.

Comment: Vou testar aqui, e dou um parecer mais tarde! Obrigado!

Comment: obrigado! Usei a forma prática! =)